# .NET Core and Azure Functions - build error System.Runtime 4.2.0.0

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm creating Azure Functions for .NET Core, following the documentations on [Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/25/develop-azure-functions-on-any-platform/) and [Github](https://github.com/lindydonna/CSharpHttpCore)

So the key for using all functionality, and the publish functions from VisualStudio is package microsoft.net.sdk.functions.

However, after adding this nuget, I get the following build error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified 
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' at System.Reflection.RuntimeA...
```

[...]
file:///C:/Users/Stefan/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/1.0.7/tools/net46/
[...]

Although the package comes with .netstandard 2.0 support, it references the net46 folder and ends up in that error...

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have `netstandard2.0` in `csproj`?

Comment: yes i checked that