# FileNotFoundException for System.Runtime 4.2.1.0 building v2 Azure Functions Project

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I'm getting an error when I try to build an Azure Functions v2 project. The odd thing is that it doesn't always happen. I've tried various combinations of Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.3) and Visual Studio 2019 (Preview 1.1), as well as building in Azure DevOps on the Hosted 2017 agent, along with changing the Functions SDK between 1.0.22, 1.0.23 and 1.0.24.

- It ALWAYS fails with this error on Azure DevOps with v1.0.24.
- It ALWAYS succeeds on VS 2019 with v1.0.24
- It ALWAYS fails with v1.0.22 on both VS 2017 and 2019
- The other combinations are kind of hit or miss whether or not they fail.

It seems somewhat similar to this question, which didn't get an answer:
[.NET Core and Azure Functions - build error System.Runtime 4.2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492362/net-core-and-azure-functions-build-error-system-runtime-4-2-0-0)

Here's the error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()

Error generating functions metadata
    FunctionsCore   C:\Users\myusername\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.24\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets   39
```

Here's my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject.FunctionsCore</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>MyProject.FunctionsCore</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And here's some of the fusion info:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/myusername/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/1.0.24/tools/net46/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Cacs.MyProject.FunctionsCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myusername/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/1.0.24/tools/net46/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myusername/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/1.0.24/tools/net46/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myusername/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/1.0.24/tools/net46/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myusername/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/1.0.24/tools/net46/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myusername/source/repos/MyProject/MyProject/FunctionsCore/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/bin/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myusername/source/repos/MyProject/MyProject/FunctionsCore/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/bin/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myusername/source/repos/MyProject/MyProject/FunctionsCore/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/bin/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myusername/source/repos/MyProject/MyProject/FunctionsCore/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/bin/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
```

Comment: Working this issue through the same in MSDN forums: [1]: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b4d5cc4-abdf-4c83-9ba5-7e1854b1a37d/filenotfoundexception-for-systemruntime-4210-building-v2-azure-functions-project?forum=AzureFunctions

Comment: I created an issue here about the same issue: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/10813
Did you find a solution since your posted your question?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the same error, but in [another context](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2000#issuecomment-456413662) (it happened when generating T4 templates in Visual Studio).

Try putting this bindingRedirect inside the `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_29f8d23a\devenv.exe.config` inside `<configuration>` -> `<runtime>` -> `<assemblyBinding>` where are all the others bindingRedirect's

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Strange that your answer had no likes yet. You will also run into this problem when combining .Net Framework and .Net Core 3.0 projects

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue , the solution for me was

- Install nuget package through package Manager console Like that:
  PM> Install-Package System.Runtime -Version 4.3.0
- Restart my computer .

Note:this worked for .Net core 1.1 MVC project.